# What is the best way to divide BN by a decimal?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, ethers.js, bignumber, decimals

I am using ethers npm library to divide BN by a decimal. The account(`0x..`) has `10.99999 GLD`.

```
const {ethers} = require('ethers');
const token = myGoldContract.balanceOf('0x....').toString();
console.log(token); // 10999999999999999970

let dividend = ethers.BigNumber.from(token)
let divisor = ethers.BigNumber.from((Math.pow(10, 18)).toString())
let result =  dividend.div(divisor);
console.log(result); //10
```

The above code will return `10` as a division result but I want the result should be something like this `10.99999`.

How can I get a division result with some digits after decimal points?

Comment: Potentially useful: [evm-bn](https://github.com/paulrberg/evm-bn) and [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 0):

[Check similar answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409977/17903686)

> You should multiply the numerator to accommodate the number of digits
> you need, perform the division and then divide with normal floating
> point division.

For example, if you want precision 2 digits after coma:

```js
// import ethers ...

let a = ethers.BigNumber.from(12300000000000000000n);
let b = ethers.BigNumber.from(1000000000000000000n);

// This
const c = Number(a.mul(100).div(b)) / 100;
console.log(c)

// Or this
const rem = a.mul(100).div(b);
console.log(a.div(100) + "." + a.mod(100));
```

Now *c* is type of number, not BigNumber.

You can't divide with a remainder directly because *ethers.BigNumber* type tries to be like *big numbers* in the *solidity* language. As you may know, *solidity* also doesn't have precision (that's why 0.5 ETH = 5e17, but not 0.5 ETH = 0.5).

Also read creator's [explanation](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/60#issuecomment-342053373).

Comment: Instead of how you defined the big numbers, you can install the [`evm-bn`](https://github.com/paulrberg/evm-bn) package and do this: `let a = toBn("123")`.